# Angular.js - Routing not working properly

Tags: angularjs

I was making a simple routing program but it is not working properly. Following is my code:

**index.html**

```
<div class="container">
    <a href="#/newEvent">Create Event</a>
<div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

**NewEvent.html**

```
<div>
    <h1>{{event.name}}</h1>
</div>
```

**EditEventController.js**

```
eventsApp.controller('EditEventController', 
    function EditEventController($scope){
        $scope.event = {name: 'Ayushi'}
});
```

**app.js**

```
var eventsApp = angular.module('eventsApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);

eventsApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/newEvent', {
            templateUrl: 'templates/NewEvent.html',
            controller: 'EditEventController'
        })
        .otherwise({redirectTo : '/'});
});
```

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: Seems working fine for me in [this plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6m8gwYai0mMdCb2vFZkb?p=preview). may be you missed to add `ng-resource` file reference.

Comment: No error on console.

Comment: look at the plunkr and digged into it, you will find your mistake by your own  :)